# How do I automate borg backup?

Tags: linux, bash, backup, shell, cron

## Background

I would like to use Borg Backup as a backup solution for my Ubuntu server.  They offer a very convenient [sh script](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#automating-backups) that they say you can just run as a cron job, but it is not working for me.

## Problem

How do I automate borg backup?  If the best way is to use cron, then what is wrong with my impementation?

## Data

#### Root's Crontab:

```
# 5 2 * * * sh /home/***/Scripts/borgBackup_run.sh >/dev/null      # Back up the root partition daily (2:05a)
* * * * * sh /home/***/Scripts/borgBackup_run.sh >/dev/null      # Test the script
```

#### borgBackup_run.sh:

Modified from the original to be very bare-bones:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Starting backup now...' >> 
/home/***/Logs/borgBackup_create.log

#/usr/bin/borg create --verbose --filter AME --list --stats --show-rc --compression lz4 --exclude-caches --one-file-system --exclude-from ~/Scripts/borgBackup_exclude.txt /mnt/RootBackup/borg::'{hostname}-{now:%Y-%m-%d}' /
/usr/bin/borg create /mnt/RootBackup/borg::cronTest /home/***/Logs/ # Backup a small folder as a test

echo 'Done.' >> /home/***/Logs/borgBackup_create.log
```

#### "ls -l ~/Scripts/borgBackup_run.sh"

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 455 Sep 27 12:34 Scripts/borgBackup_run.sh
```

#### Notes:

When `borgBackup_run.sh` is run from the commandline, as: `sudo Scripts/borgBackup_run.sh`, the script works perfectly, creating a new archive in `/mnt/RootBackup/borg`.

Additionally, after each minute (when the cronjob runs), the .log file at `/home/***/Logs/borgBackup_create.log` shows both `Starting backup now...` and `Done.`, indicating that the script has run all the way through, but borg did not work for some reason.

I have tried removing `sh` from the crontab file, using `bash` instead, and changing the interobang to `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`.  I have also tried wrapping the line `/user/bin/borg create ...` line in `borgBackup_run.sh` in `bash -c "..."`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what does borg itself say? I see you've tried options like `--verbose` and `--stats`. Surely the stdout/stderr goes somewhere; either to root's email inbox, or to the local /var/spool/mail/root mailbox, or at least to syslog.

Comment: Change the end of the crontab entry from ‘>/dev/null’ to ‘>/path/to/somewhere/cron_output 2>&1’ and see if you catch anything meaningful in that file.  Also the /usr/bin/borg..... line of the script doesn’t seem to be re-directing output to your .log file.  Currently output would be sent to /dev/null

Comment: Thank you for both of your comments!  @grawity: I previously had the stdout of borg directed to that same `borgBackup_create.log` file, however I will try redirecting strerr, as well.

Comment: @Tyson: I had directed the stdout and stderr of the script in the cron file to a log previously.  It creates the .log file, but does not add any content.

Comment: Just suggesting what I’ve done in the past to solve cron issues.  In one case a typo didn’t become obvious until I quit trashing stdout and errout at the cron level.

Comment: As it turns out, I have no idea what I'm doing, and had been attempting to redirect stdout and stderr incorrectly (I thought that `&>` would redirect both for some reason).  After more testing, it turns out `borg` was attempting to run in interactive mode.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the problem, and am posting the solution in case anyone in the future has a similar problem.

I set up my repository to be unencrypted, which caused `borg` to attempt to run interactively (asking stdout if backing up to an unencrypted repository is ok).  To make borg run non-interactively, I had to export an "automatic answerer" in `borgBackup_run.sh`, before the call to `borg create ...`.  The new line in the script looks like:

```
export BORG_UNKNOWN_UNENCRYPTED_REPO_ACCESS_IS_OK=yes
```

The name of this variable was found in the `man` page for `borg`.  A number of other "automatic answerers" can also be found in the `man` page, to ensure that borg runs non-interactively in a script.

Answer (score 6):

I just finished creating a similar cron script. Included is a sync of the borg backup files to BackBlaze's cloud storage platform (similar to amazon s3, but cheaper). Hopefully this will be useful to someone else looking for automating borg with a low-cost offsite backup!

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Starting backup for `date`\n"

# setup script variables
export BORG_PASSPHRASE="secret-passphrase-here!"
export BORG_REPO="/path/to/repo"
export BACKUP_TARGETS="/path1/to/backup /path2/to/backup"
export BACKUP_NAME="backup-and-remote-folder-name"

# create borg backup archive
cmd="borg create ::`date +%Y%m%d`-$BACKUP_NAME $BACKUP_TARGETS --stats"
$cmd

# prune old archives to keep disk space in check
borg prune -v --list --keep-daily=3 --keep-weekly=2

# sync backups to offsite storage
b2 authorize-account accountID applictionKey
b2 sync --delete --replaceNewer $BORG_REPO b2://bucket-name/$BACKUP_NAME

# all done!
echo "Backup complete at `date`\n";
```

Currently running once a day with the following crontab

```
0 11 * * * /path/to/script/backup.sh >> /path/to/logfile/backup.log 2>&1
```

Requires a BackBlaze account and their CLI tool [CLI installati](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/quick_command_line.html)

Answer (score 1):

[`borgmatic`](https://torsion.org/borgmatic/) was created for exactly this purpose and is a wrapper around brog. Create a `.yaml` config file, and then run `borgmatic`. Follow this [cron guide](https://torsion.org/borgmatic/) and you're good to go.